# Return id of a column cel

Tags: java, android

Hey will this return the id of a date inserted in the parameters so imagine if the date inserted is 01-07-2017 and his id on the table is 4 , it will return 4 ?

```
COL_1="ID";
COL_4="DATES";

public int getDateId(String date){
    int dateID=0;
    String last_query = "SELECT " + COL_1  + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME  + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " = '" + date + "'";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(last_query, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
    {
        dateID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID"));
    }
    c.close();

    return dateID;
}
```

For me is returning 0.

Im calling this method here :

```
    @Override
    public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {


        if(DatesList.contains(date)){
            myDB = CustomApplication.getDatabaseHelper();

            final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

            String printedData = df.format(date.getTime());


            int dateID = myDB.getDateId(printedData);
            Log.d(Tag,""+dateID);
            String returnedData = myDB.getDates(dateID);

            Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),TesteInfoDisplay.class);



            startActivity(i);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Não tem nenhum teste nesse dia.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
};
```

Database : https://gist.github.com/Poreis/2305632568388077be0ba122d029d3c7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just index number instead of

> c.getColumnIndex("ID")

and try this

```
     COL_1="ID"
 COL_4="DATES"

     public int getDateId(String date){
int dateID=0;
String last_query = "SELECT " + COL_1  + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME  + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " = '" + date + "'";
Cursor c = database.rawQuery(last_query, null);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
{
    dateID = c.getInt(0);
}
c.close();

return dateID;
}
```

Im calling this method here :

```
    @Override
    public void onSelectDate(Date date, View view) {


        if(DatesList.contains(date)){
            myDB = CustomApplication.getDatabaseHelper();

            final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

            String printedData = df.format(date.getTime());


            int dateID = myDB.getDateId(printedData);
            Log.d(Tag,""+dateID);
            String returnedData = myDB.getDates(dateID);

            Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),TesteInfoDisplay.class);



            startActivity(i);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Não tem nenhum teste nesse dia.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
};
```

Database : 
 https://gist.github.com/Poreis/2305632568388077be0ba122d029d3c7

Comment: It keeps returning 0

Comment: And im sure I putted like you and that there is a value there

Comment: try this `dateID = c.getLong("ID");`

Comment: can you add your database??

Comment: by the way why long ?

Comment: its because in database the values of the month are 7, and here im displaying 07

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149201/discussion-between-upendra-shah-and-emanuel-sobreiro).

Comment: Yes I did I changed , when I inputed the values the format form to dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

This looks a little more complicated then what you had but should retrieve the info you are looking for. I wrote this is a hurry so sorry if not all the variable names are exactly what you had.

```
    String[] projections = {
            "ID"
    };


    String selection = "DATES" + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = {date};


    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
            projections,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        long itemID = (cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ID")));
        Log.d(TAG, "ITEM _ID : "+ itemID);
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: yes that is correct. Don't forget to close the cursor when done with it via cursor.close()

Comment: It keeps returning 0

Comment: Have you confirmed that the id of the date you are retrieving is in fact not 0 and was saved as some other value?

Comment: Yes I did its the valor 45